# Validate form base on dropdown's value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

i want to validate a minimum value in input but this value related to what the dropdown value is

means that i have input and dropdown :

[image]

and also JQUERY to validate :

```
   <script>

    (function ($, W, D) {
        var JQUERY4U = {};

        JQUERY4U.UTIL =
        {  

            setupFormValidation: function () {
                //form validation rules

                $("#register-form").validate({

                    rules: {
                        Value:{ 
                  "required",
                  min: ($('#Currency').val ==1 ? 1000:5000 ),

                   }
   },
                    messages: {
                       Value: "Minimum Value should be ...",

  },
                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
    }
    }

    //when the dom has loaded setup form validation rules
            $(D).ready(function ($) {
                JQUERY4U.UTIL.setupFormValidation();
            });

    })(jQuery, window, document);
    </script>
```

i have tried :
 min: ($('#Currency').val ==1 ? 1000:5000 ),

but does not work

my goal is if user select dropdown value 1 , min should be 10000
if select value 2 ,min should be 5000

any idea please

thanks

Comment: Posting screenshots of code is not allowed.  Please cut & paste or re-type your code.  I am referring to your HTML markup.  Otherwise, your code will not show up in SO searches and it's more difficult for people to copy the code in order to assist you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 min: ($('#Currency').val ==1 ? 1000:5000 )
```

should be

```
 min: ($('#Currency').val() ==1 ? 1000:5000 )
```